# RDS CPU Credits decreasing faster than possible

Tags: amazon-web-services, postgresql, amazon-rds

A few days ago, I created a Postgres RDS t2.micro instance. I didn't use it at all beyond connecting to it and verifying that simple queries perform as expected. However, the CPU graph is a bit strange:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/BcVCCwe.png]

That isn't the strangest part though. Here is the CPU credit balance during the time where the CPU load decreases significantly:

[image: https://i.imgur.com/vCGuEHK.png]

As you can see, about 70 CPU credits are used in the span of ~15-30 minutes. On a micro instance, with only 1 CPU, this doesn't make a whole lot of sense.

What could be causing this usage pattern?

Comment: The VM probably restarted.

Comment: Significantly more zoom is needed on the area where the balance dropped, but as @womble suggested, a balance of 30 credits per vCPU is a magic value that indicates a stop/start of a VM. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/t2-std.html#launch-credits  Did you stop the RDS instance or was there anything shown in the events?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I didn't manually reboot it, but the uptime looks like it reset around that time. Before the reboot, "RDS Processes" took around 4% of the CPU constantly, but not really afterwards